# iframe change html content - any "render finished" event?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I modify an iframe's HTML content dynamically, how do I know when the HTML-loading is finished?

```
<iframe id="myIframe" />
<script>
    var iframeDoc = document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document;
    iframeDoc.innerHTML = "<html>complex html with external stylesheets/images</html>";
    //this can take 1-10 secs to visually render b/c of external css/imgs
</script>
```

Tried adding `onload` to iframe element both programmatically and declaratively via html-tag, doesn't work.

Also tried `iframeDoc.write`, the `srcdoc` attribute instead of changing `innerHTML`, didn't help

PS. Please note, this is about modifying the iframe's (or any element's) HTML directly, not about changing the `src` attribute that will obviously fire an `onload` event

Comment: You are not really “loading” a document into the iframe here, not in the traditional definition of “loading” meaning HTTP request anyway, so I doubt you can get this to fire a load event. (If you were to use `srcdoc` instead to supply the iframe content, then I suppose maybe that could work.) Not sure if the document’s `readyState` reflects any changes in such a scenario, maybe try that.

Comment: Maybe instead of using innerHTML to set the iframe content, you could create a Blob containing your HTML document first, and then use `createObjectURL` to get something you can then assign to the src attribute of the iframe? I imagine that might perhaps fire a load event, since that is closer to “tranditional” loading of a document, than manipulating innerHTML …?

Comment: @CBore I tried `srcdoc`, and direct `document.write` into the iframe instead of changing `innerHTML`, didn't help. In your last comment - do you mean setting `src` to something like `src=data:text/html....`? Thanks for the idea, will try that!

Comment: Data URI could be one way to go, but that won’t work in IE/Edge, https://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri I meant this, create a Blob like in the example here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob#Example, and then make that into a URL you can assign as iframe source using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: @CBroe yep, it does work, thanks! Can you please copy-paste your answer into a comment so I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not really “loading” a document into the iframe here, not in the traditional definition of “loading” meaning HTTP request anyway, so I doubt you can get this to fire a load event.

Using a Data URI to set the iframe content could be one way to go, but that won’t work in IE/Edge (https://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri)

Create a **Blob** containing your HTML document, and then use `createObjectURL` to create a URL you can assign to the iframe source. That way, it should behave the same way as “normal” loading of a document into the iframe via an HTTP(S) URL would, and therefor fire the same events you’d expect in that case, too.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob#Example
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Answer (score 0):

There many restrictions with **Same-origin security policy** with `iframes`, you can't directly execute a script from an iframe to the parent window, but since the `iframe` has its own life cycle you can communicate them using the `postMessage()` API.

> The window.postMessage() method safely enables cross-origin
>   communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a
>   pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded
>   within it.

The important part of communicating both is:

```
<body onLoad="parent.postMessage('done', '*')"></body>
```

*You will get the same result if you add the listener through a script tag*

```js
var iframe = document.querySelector('#myIframe');

iframe.srcdoc = "<html><body onLoad=\"parent.postMessage('loaded', '*')\">complex html with external stylesheets/images</body></html>";

window.addEventListener('message', function(event) { 
  console.log('The iframe says:' + event.data);
});
```

```html
<iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>
```

OR using it with data URI:

```js
var iframe = document.querySelector('#myIframe');
var html = "<html><body onLoad=\"parent.postMessage('loaded', '*')\">complex html with external stylesheets/images</body></html>";

iframe.src = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(html);

window.addEventListener('message', function(event) { 
  console.log('The iframe says:' + event.data);
});
```

```html
<iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>
```

But of course, you have the limitation in IE which doesn't support `srcdoc` either data URI

Comment: my iframe is `about:blank`, CORS is not even relevant here. The HTML source is included in the question.

Comment: I was not referring to CORS but Same-origin security policy, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: @Alex I have updated the answer following your template

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this to know when its loaded

```
document.getElementById('my_iframe').onload = function() {
    // Your actions here
}
```

Comment: I explicitly mentioned in the question that `onload` doesn't work